Dataflow Job Fails with Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory and PERMISSION_DENIED Errors
I'm working on a data migration personal project where I need to transfer multiple tables from  Microsoft SQL Server AdventureWorks2019 database to Google BigQuery using Dataflow SQL Server to BQ template. The goal is to use the SQL to BQ or JDBC to BQ template not cloud shell or python. My pipeline fails with the following errors:
2024-06-29 22:12:13.949 CST
Error message from worker: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The TCP/IP connection to the host xx.xx.xx.xxx, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:803)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1792)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$3000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:143)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2650)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$2.processElement(MapElements.java:151)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$2$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:803)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:213)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver.multiplexElements(BeamFnDataInboundObserver.java:158)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:537)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:150)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:115)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:163)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The TCP/IP connection to the host xx.xx.xx.xxx, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:653)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:531)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:731)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn.getConnection(JdbcIO.java:1526)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn.processElement(JdbcIO.java:1539)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host xx.xx.xx.xxx, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:237)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.convertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:288)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2574)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:715)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3427)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3077)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2919)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1787)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1229)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:52)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:374)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:106)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:649)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:531)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:731)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn.getConnection(JdbcIO.java:1526)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn.processElement(JdbcIO.java:1539)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:803)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1792)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$3000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:143)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2650)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$2.processElement(MapElements.java:151)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$2$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:803)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:213)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver.multiplexElements(BeamFnDataInboundObserver.java:158)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:537)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:150)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:115)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:163)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
{
insertId: "k9av4id28fi"
labels: {4}
logName: "projects/xxxx-xxxxxxx-project/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message"
receiveTimestamp: "2024-06-30T04:12:15.797585260Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "Error message from worker: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The TCP/IP connection to the host xx.xx.xx.xxx, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:803)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1792)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$3000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:143)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2650)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$2.processElement(MapElements.java:151)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$2$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:803)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:213)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver.multiplexElements(BeamFnDataInboundObserver.java:158)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:537)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:150)
    org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:115)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:163)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
"
timestamp: "2024-06-30T04:12:13.949046311Z"
}

My connjdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.xx.xxx:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks2019;user=xxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxx;
Steps I have taken:

Configured SQL Server for remote connection.
Enabled TCP/IP and configured IP and port settings.
Configured Windows Firewall to allow SQL Server traffic on port 1433.
To verify the JDBC connection, I wrote and compiled a Java program that successfully connected to    the SQL Server using the provided JDBC URL, username, and password on PowerShell.
Successfully connected and queried the AdventureWorks2019 DB from a different machine (Mac) within the same network.
Created a Google Cloud project and set up a Dataflow job to read from SQL Server.
Added necessary IAM roles for the service account used by Dataflow:

BigQuery Admin
BigQuery Data Editor
Compute Network User
Data Pipelines Admin
Dataflow Admin
Dataflow Worker
Pub/Sub Publisher
Storage Admin
Storage Object Admin
Storage Object Creator
Storage Object Viewer
VMware Engine Service Admin


Created a BigQuery table: BigQuery Output Table
Successfully ran the sample Dataflow 'wordcount' template.


Please note there is a preview section for the post for a reason. Taking a moment to review the preview and make sure it appears appropriately is something you should be taking the time to do before posting.

Hi @ThomA, thank you for your comment. As this is my first time posting a question on the platform, I'd appreciate it if you could clarify your point further. I'm not quite sure what you mean, and I'd love some additional insight.

What's the flow here, do you connect from the cloud to some local computer where sql server is? Or from local computer to big query and some local sql server

@siggemannen, The data migration job involves transferring data from the AdventureWorks2019 database on a local SQL Server (my Windows computer) to Google BigQuery. The steps include:
SQL Server Configuration:
Configure the SQL Server for remote connections.
Ensure firewall rules allow external access.
GCP Dataflow Job Creation:
Use my Mac computer to create and configure the Dataflow job.
The job reads data from the SQL Server via JDBC.
Data Transfer Process:
The job transfers data to a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket.
Data is then loaded into Google BigQuery

Hmm, the Dataflow-job, wouldn't it run from Google's own servers?

@siggemannen
Can you clarify what you mean? I think the issue stems from vpc/network settings in gcp but not sure. I Successfully ran the sample Dataflow 'wordcount' template

If you look at the original revision of your post, @Cjizzle , you'll note it lacked any formatting and was more or less unreadable. Formatting goes a long way to having other users have interest in reading your post; not everyone is happy to spend several minutes editting a post into a position where they can read it.
